# Minimax and Connect 4?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, computer-science

Principal Variation Searches are commonly implemented in chess AI algorithms. Can this algorithm be used when using Minimax to place Connect 4?

If so, how? I thought about this for a while, but could't figure out how the PVS could be applied to Connect 4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about connect 4. PVS is a very simple modification of alpha-beta algorithm which can be applied to any game (turn-based, full information etc. but connect4 fullfills all the assumptions).

So the answer is "it can be usde, in the exact same form as always".

For more details, including pseudocode and long discussion you can look it up [here](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Principal+Variation+Search)

Answer (score 0):

A really nice Tutorial about Connect 4 and how to implement a **PERFECT connect 4 AI** with Minimax/Negamax: http://blog.gamesolver.org/

.

EDIT: as Blastfurnace mentions. I forgot to mainly answer the question.

So Yes Minimax can be used for connect for i personally would use NegaMax but it's only a small optimization.

And HOW you could implement Minimax is described in the link above.